# use back_inserter within C++ transform algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, transform

```
vector<string> v = {"AAAAidad", "bbbb", "ADWHIBQSDS", "Hi", "fes", "dafegrg", "QQEEQEQEQEQ
    E", "\"", "a"};
transform1(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(v),
                     [] (string s) -> string{
                     for(char& c:s)
                     {
                          c = toupper(c);
                     }
                    return s;
                    });
```

with the code snippet above, I expect to insert capitalized string element at the end of v.
Actually, however, I just get the following output

```
v = {"AAAAidad",    "bbbb", "ADWHIBQSDS",   "Hi",   "fes",  "dafegrg",  "QQEEQEQEQEQ",    "AAAAIDAD"}
```

Only the first string was capitalized and inserted.
Where are the rest string element in the vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Useless Maybe you are right, I use a customized transform1 to solve it. And this time I didn't use the cached end iterator.
Thank you!

```
 20 template<class Input,  class OutputIt, class UnaryOperation>
 21 OutputIt transform1(Input input, OutputIt d_first, UnaryOperation unary_op)
 22 {
 23     auto first1 = input.begin();
 24     while(first1 != input.end())                                                                                                      
 25     {
 26         *d_first++ = unary_op(*first1++);
 27     }
 28     return d_first;
 29 }
```

Comment: If `d_first` is an `back_insert_iterator` on `input` this is still likely to fail. (It probably will work in your case, because you pass `input` by value -- which itself is not a good idea)

Comment: I think you are right, I should pass input by reference. And I try it and compile it. But I just got a segment fault.  Would you help me?@chtz

Answer (score 5):

When you assign to a [`back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), it calls `push_back` on the underlying container.

Calling [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) on a vector invalidates at least the `end` iterator, and possibly everything else.

The begin and end iterators you pass into `transform` can be invalidated at any time during the traversal, at which point the whole thing exhibits Undefined Behaviour.

---

Here's a version that doesn't have UB, and doesn't require a custom transform function:

```
const auto original_size = v.size();

// add original_size empty strings at the end
v.resize(original_size * 2);

// the first new empty string is also one-past-the end of the originals
auto first_empty = v.begin() + original_size;

transform(v.begin(), first_empty, first_empty, strtoupper);
```

where `strtoupper` is your original lambda, or, you could just re-use transform:

```
std::string strtoupper(std::string s) {
    transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), toupper);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Could you help me to correct it. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Thank U. I want to point that toupper in strtoupper need to be changed as ::toupper.